# Replacing localStorage with new values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am reading the values from localStorage as nested array and based on some conditions, I am deleting few arrays from the read array.  To delete the arrays from master array, I am using the following function:

```
Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};
```

The resultant array is smaller than the original nested array.  The following is my **original array** from localStorage:

```
var arr = `"["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",270,399,387,397,390,472,"STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",270,399,387,397,390,472,"STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",321,322,414,333,418,375]"`

//Function to drop rectangles
function dropRects() {
    dragging = false;
    mLocation = getCanvasCoordinates(event);
    var a = Math.floor(mLocation.x);
    var b = Math.floor(mLocation.y);
    var clickedImg = localStorage.getItem('clickedImage');
    var arr = new Array();
    var getCoords = getArray();
    if (typeof getCoords !== 'undefined' && getCoords.length > 0) {
      var allCoords = fourthCoord(getCoords);
      arr = multiDimensionalUnique(allCoords);
```

the example array `arr` given above is the result of `multiDimensionalUnique(allCoords);

```
      var results = new Array();
    //For each item in array, perform calculation to find the array that needs to be deleted and store the found array in results - This is working properly

      arr.forEach(function(d) {
        if (d[0] === clickedImg && d[3] < a && d[4] < b && d[5] > a && d[6] < b && d[7] > a && d[8] > b && d[9] < a && d[10] > b) {
          results.push(d)
        }
      });
    //delete the found array from master array.
      var newArr;
      newArr = arr.diff(results);

     //Delete the empty array [] from the master array
      var secArr;
      secArr = newArr.filter(function(x) { return (x !== (undefined || null || ''));})

      //Delete the last two elements from each array, so that it is exactly the same as array downloaded from localStorage
      for (var i = 0;i < secArr.length; i++) {
        secArr[i].splice(9,2);  
      }
      secArr = JSON.stringify(secArr) 
      console.log(secArr);
  } 
  localStorage.setItem('coords', secArr);
}
```

The `console.log(secArr)` prints the following result **(new array)**:

```
[["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","FBB",270,406,377,396,381,469],["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",326,321,425,332,420,375],["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00143.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",367,323,492,330,492,378]]
```

I am not sure why I have an extra square bracket at the beginning and at the end of this array.  (pardon me if this result is different from the example data given above, as this is from my live dashboard)

And the line `localStorage.setItem('coords', secArr)`  resets the localStorage with the new values which looks like this:

```
"[["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","FBB",270,406,377,396,381,469],["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",326,321,425,332,420,375],["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00143.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",367,323,492,330,492,378]]"
```

again with preceeding and succeeding square brackets.

Since the new array is nested within another array, when I read the localStorage again, I am not able to retrieve the array.  How do I post `secArr` variable into localStorage as my original `coords` variable.

Comment: What's up with the quotes, man! Aren't there a few too many outer double quotes in your strings?

Comment: I mean, on `var arr=` declaration on the second snippet, and on the last result.

Comment: Your output is an array of arrays because of `result.push(d)` since `d` is an array.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I too believe so...earlier I had declared `newArr` and `secArr` too as arrays...but then changed them....I am not sure how to push new values into a variable that is not an array

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your answer is due to the double quotes in the `var arr` declaration. Please look at the following code:

```
arr = ["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",270,399,387,397,390,472,"STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",270,399,387,397,390,472,"STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",321,322,414,333,418,375];

Array.prototype.diff = function(a) {
    return this.filter(function(i) {return a.indexOf(i) < 0;});
};
clickedImg = true;

var results = new Array();
//For each item in array, perform calculation to find the array that needs to be deleted and store the found array in results - This is working properly

arr.forEach(function(d) {
  if (d[0] === clickedImg && d[3] < a && d[4] < b && d[5] > a && d[6] < b && d[7] > a && d[8] > b && d[9] < a && d[10] > b) {
    results.push(d)
  }
});
//delete the found array from master array.
var newArr;
newArr = arr.diff(results);

//Delete the empty array [] from the master array
var secArr;
secArr = newArr.filter(function(x) { return (x !== (undefined || null || ''));})

//Delete the last two elements from each array, so that it is exactly the same as array downloaded from localStorage
for (var i = 0;i < secArr.length; i++) {
  secArr[i].splice(9,2);  
}
secArr = JSON.stringify(secArr) 
console.log(secArr);
```

It produces
`["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","FBB",270,406,377,396,381,469],["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00142.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",326,321,425,332,420,375],["STAR_SPORTS_2-20170924-200043-210917-00143.jpg","PerimeterBoard","Gillette",367,323,492,330,492,378]` (notice no array within array).

Comment: Is it because that you have not actually deleted an array..coz if you see the initial set `arr` and `secArr` is one and the same.